# Listbox Items in VBNET

Tags: vb.net, forms, events, listbox, click

I'm working on code that creates a form with two list boxes. In the first list box I'm listing a set of items in a Civil 3D file (wich is already working). In the second list box I want to show all the sub items of the items that are listed in the first list box.

In other words, when I open the form, the first list box contain all the items (already working), when I click or double click one of this items, the second list box will list all the sub items that is in this item that I clicked.

Any ideas in how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code and where it is failing.

Comment: Use the SelectedIndexChanged then grab which record was selected and run your query.